# How to make a gem work with newer version of dependencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

I am using [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) gem and it requires sinatra (>= 0.9.2)

This installs Sinatra 1.0 gem which produces an error like `loadError: cannot load such file -- rack/showexceptions`

This is an issue fixed in Sinatra version 1.4.7, but I can't make resque to work with 1.4.7, even if version 1.4.7 is installed, bundle install still install version 1.0

Comment: You can't. There is no easy solution to make two incompatible pieces of software just work. Upgrade one, or downgrade the other.

Comment: do you insist on resque ? there are alternatives like delayed_job, beanneater(using beanstalkd) and others.

Comment: The gemspec for that gem only requires sinatra >= 0.9.2 - are you sure there isn't something else stopping a more recent version being used?

Comment: I did a dependency check, and it stated that sinatra 1.0 is required by resque

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fork the project on GitHub. Replace the dependency version [here](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/resque.gemspec#L24). Run the test and if everything passes create a pull request.

```
s.add_dependency "sinatra", ">= 0.9.2"

# to this
s.add_dependency "sinatra", "~> 1.4"
```

Alternatively, you will have to your own gem and use it in your project. But that obviously has its disadvantages! That should be your last resort.